# How to tell whether a 0x address is a wallet or a contract?

Tags: erc-20, wallets, contract-invocation, hex

This as an Ethereum wallet address:

- 0x983110309620D911731Ac0932219af06091b6744

This is a token contract address (ERC-20, WETH):

- 0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2

As you can see they are indistinguishable, both starting with 0x, but have very different functionalities.

Is there a way to tell whether a 0x address is a wallet or a contract, besides comparing their websites on Etherscan?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to tell just by looking at the string. You would need to look into the code to see the difference.

Comment: does a wallet even have code? what difference would tell them apart

Comment: I mean that just gets down to the nitty gritty in the solidity code etc. That is a bit over my head. Of course wallets have code, but just coded differently.

Comment: Wonder if someone can demonstrate that difference with code examples